# Filter email with image in body of an email

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to find better solution than filtering emails by this filter

> has:attachment larger:25kb (filename:jpg OR filename:gif OR filename:png)

because Gmail filtered everything with attachment, but I need filter only email with an image in the body of an email.

Comment: That could be a little tough, because it may depend on how the image is embedded.

Comment: The first question that is it a possible to check _is image in mail body_.
Secondary I can check e.g. width.

Comment: For me, the "has:attachment" search operator finds lots of emails without attachments, however, these emails usually have images embedded (i.e. not attached). Is this intended behavior?

Comment: I think It is a correct behavior according programmatically, but It is not user friendly. Unfortunately I did not find better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regarding [the official documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) there is no way to search for an embedded image.

By the way you can simplify the query a little:
`has:attachment larger:25kb filename:(jpg OR gif OR png)`

Comment: ad Reply -> in an official documentation sometimes something missing
ad BTW -> yeah, it is true